# What is the upper bound for the index of refraction of space?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, gravitational-waves

It seems that gravitational waves and gamma waves travail at [about the same speed](https://doi.org/10.3847/2041-8213/aa920c), arriving within seconds of each other over distances in the ranges of $10^6$LY. Naively, I would assume this caps the index of refraction (for gamma waves in intergalactic space) to something like $1+10^{-13}$. However I expect I'm making rather a lot of unfounded assumptions and probably missing a number of other things.

Has anyone actually worked through the physics and math to get a good answer to that question? What about the related question for different wavelengths or other, more dense, locations like interstellar space?